# javascript redirect won't work?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I have a little bit of javascript code that is getting some parameters from php. the php variable $rid is an integer with a value within 1-100. what i am trying to do is change the value of the 'rid' variable in the querystring by a specified amount (offset). when i remove the last `str($rid)` characters from `window.location.href`, i am left with `http://www.qwerty.asdf/uiop?rid=`. When I add `<?php echo $rid;?>+offset`to it I get `http://www.qwerty.asdf/uiop?rid=2` for example. when I try the code, nothing happens, but I've debugged and str is the desired value by the time I say `window.location.href=str;`

why doesnt the page redirect? I have tried window.location as opposed to window.location.href, but it doesn't work.

p.s. there is no other javascript on the page

```
function moveRid(offset) {
    str = window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.length-<?php echo strlen($rid);?>);
    rid = <?php echo $rid;?>+offset;
    str += rid;
    window.location.href=str;
}
```

Comment: If there is no other JS on the page, when and how is that function being called? onload/click?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the window.location

```
function moveRid(offset) {
    str = window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.length-<?php echo strlen($rid);?>);
    rid = <?php echo $rid;?>+offset;
    str += rid;
    //window.location.href=str;
    window.location = str;
}
```

Comment: i've tried this and it does not work... i thought window.location.href was the "right way" to do it so that's what I did.

Comment: What do you see when you do alert(str) right above my window.location = str;  ?

Comment: that's what I meant by debugging, and i get: `http://www.mysite.com/file.php?rid=2` yet i stay at `http://www.mysite.com/file.php?rid=1`